# BroadcastReceiver does not start Activity correctly

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I wrote an app that works heavily with sending and receiving sms. Actually it sends some commands to a device and get the answer from that device to show to the user.
I defined main Activity of this app as below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

It is defined as singleTask to avoid having multiple instances running at the same time. 
Inside MainActivity, I added onNewIntent() method to get new calls to this Activity while it is running in foreground:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    handleNewMessage(this.getIntent());
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    // ...
    handleNewMessage(intent);       
}
```

Inside sms BroadcastReceiver, I start this activity with a FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_BODY", sms.getBody());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that

1- sometimes I get 3-4 text messages but MainActivity does not start. If I get a call, or unlock the phone all of the messages start the app (MainActivity) at the same time!

2- I want to turn screen on for 2-3 seconds and unlock the phone automatically after getting text message but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `WakeLock` as below"

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
    // your code ...
    wl.release();
}
```